# What has changed in angularjs 1.2.0rc1 to 1.2.0, that breaks this code?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to know what changes in angularjs from version 1.2.0rc to 1.2.0, that breaks this code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Iwptv

I know how to correct, just replace

```
    ng-click="alertar({{$index}})"
```

by

```
    ng-click="alertar($index)"
```

Why ng-click has a different behavior from other elements, like class or id, where the use of curly braces is still necessary? It was a breaking change?

Comment: class and id is not angularjs directive. Basically you don't need to use curly braces for ng-click anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is caused by this one [79223eae](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/79223eae5022838893342c42dacad5eca83fabe8)

> Previously, the interpolation priority was -100 in 1.2.0-rc.2, and 100
>   before 1.2.0-rc.2. Before this change the binding was setup in the
>   post-linking phase.
>
> Now the attribute interpolation (binding) executes as a directive with
>   priority 100 and the binding is set up in the pre-linking phase.

However, according to the [document](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClick)

```
<ANY ng-click="{expression}">
```

So I think you shouldn't use curly braces